# > / < / === three way comparison without having to write the compared values more than once?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to write a solution to a problem that requires three possible different return values depending on the result of two values. The possibilities are **greater than**, **less than**, or **equal to**. An easy and understandable way to write this would be:

```js
function compare(x, y) {
  if (x < y) return y;
  if (x > y) return x;
  if (x === y) return 'equal';
}
```

I've been trying to figure out if there are ways to write this by reducing the number of occurrences of `x`, `y`, `if`, and `return` in the code. For instance, if I'm not checking for `===`, then I can eliminate `if` and reduce `return` to one use:

```js
function compare(x, y) {
  return x > y ? x : y;
}
```

Adding `===` back into this ternary return is clunkier, and I'm not a fan of using ternary operators when there are more than two possibilities. This could be really difficult to read if `x` and `y` were replaced by long expressions:

```js
function compare(x, y) {
  return x === y ? 'equal' : x > y ? x : y;
}
```

I could also do:

```js
function compare(x, y) {
  if (x !== y) {
    return x > y ? x : y;
  }
  return 'equal';
}
```

which could be more readable than the function above, especially if `x` and `y` are replaced with expressions.

Using a switch in this case could be overkill -- but maybe not? Is there another solution to this? Is there a way to store the result of comparing `x` and `y` and then checking what that value is? Is it even worth the trouble at that point?

Comment: I think I would prefer your last code, except I would check for the *positive* `===`, and `return 'equal'` inside the `if` block (looks a *bit* better IMO). You can separate out the nested conditionals onto multiple lines to make it more readable, though unfortunately it doesn't get *that* much more readable. IMO `switch` would *definitely* be worse, it's so verbose and error-prone

Comment: Your first function is redundant. You can just `return 'equal'` after your first two if statements. The second function is kind of hard to read. I would use the first or third function.

Comment: If there were more than 3 conditions, you could generalize and make things DRY with an array or object of some sort, but for only 3 conditions, it's not really worth it

Comment: @StarCoder ah yeah, I didn't catch that. I think ESLint would have complained about that

Comment: `const compare = (x, y) => x === y ? 'equal' : Math.max(x, y)` this looks more readable to me.

Comment: Did you consider the case that `x` and `y` are neither equal, smaller or greater - e.g. if one or both of them are `NaN`? Notice that your first solution does return a *fourth* value, `undefined`, which is probably undesirable.

Comment: @Bergi that's a good point -- I guess I should have put that we can assume x and y are numbers, or could have enforced types in the example

Comment: It seems to be strange to me that the function returns two different kinds of results: If the values are different, it returns one of the values. If the values are the same, it returns something that describes the relationship of the values. Can you provide examples how this function is used eventually? Maybe there is a better way to design this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could take only one comparison and return either `'equal'` or the max value.

```js
function compare(x, y) {
    return x === y
        ? 'equal'
        : Math.max(x, y);
}

console.log(compare(1, 2));
console.log(compare(2, 2));
console.log(compare(2, 1));
```